# Broken drive permissions API - blank domain value

Tags: google-drive-api

When looking up permissions of a particular file, the domain value always appear blank for user belonging to either gmail.com or a domain managed by google business apps. A blank domain is totally breaking our app since we have no way to know the domain the user belongs to. Please help.

Below is the output of the list permission call API. Mary Smith and Tammy Smith belong to two different domains, however both the domains are managed by google business apps

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permissionList",
  "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/85B6sgFWKSZAAnkp_aGSi_fQbVw\"",
  "selfLink": "...",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "drive#permission",
      "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/dSzQR3bvSCqqYJS_1w3uteVH7l0\"",
      "id": "13993319320534768416",
      "selfLink": "...",
      "name": "Mary Smith",
      "emailAddress": "mary.smith@XXXX-inc.com",
      "domain": "XXXX-inc.com",
      "role": "owner",
      "type": "user"
   },
   {

     "kind": "drive#permission",
     "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/F80isegNBXt9znQxi_magW5XUEg\"",
     "id": "03126377218273228506",
     "selfLink": "...",
     "name": "Tammy Smith",
     "domain": "",
     "role": "writer",
     "type": "user"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without domain or/and emailAddress information it is difficult to know if the document belongs to a user within the enterprise or not. Is this bug appearing because of multiple domains (or aliases) defined for google business account. Urgently need help. Thanks.

Comment: I see the same issue for a user with a gmail account sharing a document. The domain value comes as blank and no email address. Still waiting for some help ...

Comment: Looks like someone reported similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218646/email-address-for-google-drive-permission